# Nodejs Http Server api Execution flow please Explain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, nodes, node-modules

I am having the following Nodejs Program

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
  console.log("Enter into the 3000 port");
  res.end("hello world")
  console.log("Enter into the 3000 port");
}).listen(3000,()=>{console.log("the server is listen to the port 3000");});
```

I am running these code while loading the localhost:3000 in browser and when i written the `console.log("Enter into the 3000 port");` to check how the execution works internally i got the following output.
OUTPUT:

```
the server is listen to the port 3000
Enter into the 3000 port
Enter into the 3000 port
Enter into the 3000 port
Enter into the 3000 port
```

But i have written the code `console.log("Enter into the 3000 port");`
two times in code but i don't understand why it called two times on single request and when i again send the request it again showed me the some output can any one explain.

Comment: Because you told it to log the same message twice on every request. Use `return res.end(message);` and/or remove the extra log.

Comment: @Luis Estevez can you explain in this in bit of depth thank you. :)

Comment: It is because of your browser called 2 times. When you do request through something like CURL, it should be print once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
  if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') { return } // if you don't serve this hit 
  console.log(req.url);
  console.log("Enter into the 3000 port");
  res.end("hello world")
  console.log("Enter into the 3000 port");
}).listen(3000,()=>{console.log("the server is listen to the port 3000");})
```

[image]

> most of the browsers look for `*favicon.ico*`  automatically you can avoid if you want

[code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/a4d8e81f-6a53-4fa6-bf6f-9f432d572dc2)

Answer (score 0):

That is normal - your browser makes more than one call.

Most browsers make a call to grab /favicon.ico for example.

Try to log the url:

```
console.log(req.url);
```

and you'll see what's being called.